# spring.cloud.kubernetes.discovery.discovery-server-url - what is the correct url?

Tags: java, spring-boot, kubernetes, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-kubernetes

I am just setting two simple services on Mac using minikube

I have the service set up and I can access it via ingress / minikube tunnel . So i know the service works

I am using Spring Boot 3, with the  so i need to specify the `spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-all` package. This means I need to specify a url for `spring.cloud.kubernetes.discovery.discovery-server-url`

When i try to do the simple call to

`discoveryClient.getServices()`

I get the error "Connection refused [https://kubernetes.docker.internal:6443/apps"](https://kubernetes.docker.internal:6443/apps%22)

"apps" is my second service

It is refusing connection to the value of `spring.cloud.kubernetes.discovery.discovery-server-url`

At the moment i have this set to `spring.cloud.kubernetes.discovery.discovery-server-url=https://kubernetes.docker.internal:6443`

I am assuming this is incorrect and I need some help as to what is the correct url to set this to / or the correct place to find this. I thought this would be the internal url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to configure your discovery client with the Kubernetes API server URL, which is incorrect.
Your client application needs to be connected to **Spring Cloud Kubernetes Discovery Server**.
It's an independent application that will work like a **proxy** between your client SpringBoot apps and Kubernetes.
You can find its images here: https://hub.docker.com/r/springcloud/spring-cloud-kubernetes-discoveryserver/tags
And it should be deployed to Kubernetes via yaml file.

Then you can configure
`spring.cloud.kubernetes.discovery.discovery-server-url`
with this discovery server URL. That URL will most likely come from a Kubernetes service that you will create for the discovery server application.

Please, find the full deployment YAML and the related documentation here:
https://spring.io/blog/2021/10/26/new-features-for-spring-cloud-kubernetes-in-spring-cloud-2021-0-0-m3

Please, let us know how that goes

Comment: So this worked. Thank you , i should have realised what i was doing wrong myself :)

I did find one issue which i am still looking to resolove the discovery server only finds services on the same namespace 

There is a fix for this listed here: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-kubernetes/issues/824

However that did not seem to work for me , but i will keep playing around with it

I can just carry on using a single namespace and come back to this issue later 

Thanks once again.